# Как сделать в prompt несколько текстовых полей?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать в prompt несколько текстовых полей, как при входе на этот сайт: [http://raftkorn.com/jquery-plavnoe-izmeneniya-prozrac...](http://raftkorn.com/jquery-plavnoe-izmeneniya-prozrachnosti/) (Не зачтите как реклама)

Comment: а где там несколько полей ? он просто авторизацию запрашивает, это заголовок http 401 через js вроде-бы не делается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В prompt нельзя сделать несколько полей. По умолчанию это окно с одним полем для ввода, кнопками Ok и Cancel. То, что вы показали, окно авторизации на сервере. Если необходимо просто всплывающее окно с полями, то его можно сделать при помощи html+jquery

Comment: Жаль, просто мне интересно как они это сделали